# Report Viewer is missing in VS 2013 for SQL EXPRESS 2014

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014-express

I didn't found the report viewer in toolbox of visual studio 2013 .I am using SQL EXPRESS 2014 edition and i developed a VB.net management software.All I need to fetch the data from SQL server and viewing those data in a report.But i don't get the solution.I don't want to use Crystal report.If any other reporting tools are available for VS 2013 and it should be free licensed please let me know.Or if you guys give me a RDLC reporting solution it will be great help for me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add reference to Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll and Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll in your project.....These are probably not included in your download of VS Express, and so you will need to get them either from an older project you have created, or go online to find them.

After you do this, you will likely need to rebuild your project in release mode, and then restart Visual Studio to get the control to appear in your toolbox.